# Can an Apify project contain several crawlers?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, apify

I was searching the documentation for it but wasn't able to find any related article.

I want to know if I can have several crawlers defined in a Apify project just like you can have several Spiders on Scrapy or if I have to create a new project for each new website that I like to crawl.

I would appreciate any response, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create as many crawler instances you need/want.

It's usually a good thing to separate things like sitemap crawling, using it's own `CheerioCrawler`/`BasicCrawler` instances with specific settings and an specific queue, then the full scraper using the desired crawler, like `PuppeteerCrawler`, also using it's own queue if needed.

You can choose to run them in parallel with

```js
await Promise.all([
   crawler1.run(), 
   crawler2.run(),
]);
```

or one at a time, using

```js
await crawler1.run();
await crawler2.run();
```

the caveat when using `Promise.all` is that if they are reading/writing to the same key-value store, you might have some racing conditions. If they don't share any state, you should be good to go.

Comment: But best practice is to have one project (we call those actor) per one website.

Comment: @LukášKřivka thank you for the feedback, then can I have several projects(actors) in a single Git repository?

Comment: @Odars yes, you can use many folders in a monorepo

Comment: The URL for inside folder is then `${gitUrl}#master:folder`

Comment: Hi, sorry to bring this up again, I'm writing an actor that will use 2 crawlers, a CheerioCrawler for pagination and a PuppeteerCrawler for detailed pages. How could I share the requestQueue between both without messing it up? Can I create 2 separate requestQueue objects and add URLs from the CheerioCrawler and then send it to the PuppeteerCrawler?

Comment: @Odars use request.userData.labels https://help.apify.com/en/articles/1829103-request-labels-and-how-to-pass-data-to-other-requests